# How to add like button in fancybox?

Tags: fancybox

I'm loading some photo by FancyBox & I need to load some widget of one social net(VKontakte(Russian Facebook)).

How can I add to load "Like Button" script in FancyBox?

Comment: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful No. 13

Answer (score 0):

You can add like this

```
$(".fancylink").fancybox({
'titlePosition': 'over',
'titleFormat': function() {
   return '<span id="fancybox-title-over"><script src="http:\/\/
connect.facebook.net\/en_US\/all.js#xfbml=1"><\/script><fb:like
href="http:\/\/www.google.com" layout="button_count"
show_faces="false" width="450"></fb:like></span>';
}
```